# Resetting IronScheme Engine in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ironscheme

Is there a way to "reset" the IronScheme engine?
I'm essentially aiming to ensure that successive calls to string.Eval() are executed independently.

For example, I want to be execute

`"(define x 1.0) (+ x 5.0)".Eval()`

then reset, and have the call

`"(+ x 3.0)".Eval()`

fail as it would if it were executed by itself.

Even better would be a way to give each of n concurrent threads its own independent space in which to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options for the REPL (with libraries it will not even allow you to write such code ;p).

**1: Reset the interaction environment.**

This can be done with `(interaction-environment (new-interaction-environment))`.

Sample:

```
> (define x 5) (+ x 5)
10
> (interaction-environment (new-interaction-environment))
> (+ x 5)
Unhandled exception during evaluation:
&undefined
&message: "attempted to use undefined symbol"
&irritants: (x)
```

**2: Create a new interaction environment that you hold on to in C#.**

If you want to concurrent environments, this is probably the best option. I use this approach for the [IronScheme online evaluator](http://eval.ironscheme.net).

Sample:

```
"(define x 1.0) (+ x 5.0)".Eval();
var env = "(new-interaction-environment)".Eval();
"(+ x 3.0)".EvalWithEnvironment(env);
```

Possible solution:

```
Func<object> reset = 
   "(lambda () (interaction-environment (new-interaction-environment)))".
   Eval<Callable>().Call;

"(define x 1.0) (+ x 5.0)".Eval();

reset();

"(+ x 5.0)".Eval();
```

Comment: @pcbulldozer: No problem :) Let me know if you have more issues.